# Junit Testing Framework for google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, junit

// My test class

I want to do junit test of the below code but it is not performing and throwing some errors. I have imported all the jar files but still the junit testing is not doing its task.

```
package com.full.notetakingapplicationtest;
    import org.junit.After;
    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Mockito;

    import static org.mockito.Mockito.atLeastOnce;

    import com.full.notetakingapplication.RegistrationClass;
    import com.full.notetakingapplication.UserDetailsClass;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
    import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalAppIdentityServiceTestConfig;
    import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
    import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;
    import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalTaskQueueTestConfig;

    import junit.framework.TestCase;

    public class UserDetailsClassTest extends TestCase {

    public final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =  new LocalServiceTestHelper(
                new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig(),
                new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig().setDisableAutoTaskExecution(true),
                new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig().setShouldCopyApiProxyEnvironment(true),          
                new LocalAppIdentityServiceTestConfig());

        @Before
        public void setUp(){
            helper.setUp();
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown(){  
            helper.tearDown();
        }

        @InjectMocks
        UserDetailsClass user = Mockito.mock(UserDetailsClass.class);

        @InjectMocks
        RegistrationClass register = new RegistrationClass();

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        @Test
        public void testRegisterUser_usingMockito(){

            String userName = "Pravin";
            String userEmailId = "pravin.bala@adaptavantcloud.com";
            String userPassword = "success";
            register.setUserName(userName);
            register.setUserEmailId(userEmailId);
            register.setUserPassword(userPassword);

            Assert.assertTrue(user.registerUser(register));
            verify(user, atLeastOnce()).registerUser(register);
        }
    }
```

// My Error on Testing the method.

```
UserDetailsClassTest.testRegisterUser_usingMockito
testRegisterUser_usingMockito(com.full.notetakingapplicationtest.UserDetailsClassTest)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.ProtocolSupport.freezeString(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.OnestoreEntity$Reference.freeze(OnestoreEntity.java:7656)
at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.OnestoreEntity$Reference$1.<init>(OnestoreEntity.java:7555)
at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.OnestoreEntity$Reference.<clinit>(OnestoreEntity.java:7552)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyTranslator.convertToPb(KeyTranslator.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityTranslator.convertToPb(EntityTranslator.java:51)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:178)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:155)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$BatchIterator.<init>(Batcher.java:180)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$2.<init>(Batcher.java:317)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher.getBatches(Batcher.java:317)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchPut(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:365)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:293)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.runInternal(BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:261)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runWriteInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:53)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:263)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:234)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:56)
    at com.full.notetakingapplication.UserDetailsClass.registerUser(UserDetailsClass.java:25)
    at com.full.notetakingapplicationtest.UserDetailsClassTest.testRegisterUser_usingMockito(UserDetailsClassTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: what are you trying to mock with the class RegistrationClass? Is it an Entity?

Comment: Registration is my main class where i have defined all my methods inside the methods all data store values are stored. That's why i am mocking my Registration Class

Comment: Can you please post this class?

Comment: public class RegistrationClass {
 String userName;
 String userEmailId;
 String userPassword;
 public String getUserName() {
  return userName;
 }
 public void setUserName(String userName) {
  this.userName = userName;
 }
 public String getUserEmailId() {
  return userEmailId;
 }
 public void setUserEmailId(String userEmailId) {
  this.userEmailId = userEmailId;
 }
 public String getUserPassword() {
  return userPassword;
 }
 public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
  this.userPassword = userPassword;
 }
}